# Peewee ORM: How get() in column value?

Tags: python, database, peewee

[image]

I am trying to select a value from a database by condition.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can we see your model definition?

Comment: ```class BaseModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = db

class Mark(BaseModel):

    mark = CharField()
    mark_description = CharField()

class Br(BaseModel):

    branch = CharField()
    branch_description = CharField()
```
@PatrickHaugh Sure! This it.

Comment: What's your result for `Br.get_by_id(1)`?

Comment: My results `Br: 1` , because peewee using autoincrement

Comment: If you can get that instance, you can inspect its `branch` attribute to see what the value actually is.  It might have some whitespace that is preventing it from matching in your original query.

Answer (score 0):

The `.get()` API requires that the row you are attempting to fetch exist, else it will raise the `DoesNotExist` exception.

Refer to the docs if you have any questions:

http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html#Model.get